# how to change interface metrics of network adapters using c#?

Tags: c#, networking

In relation to the  link below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577406/enable-both-lan-intranet-and-usb-internet

Is there a  way to do it using a c# programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Code Project article that shows you how to do it:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/winnetstat.aspx

Basically, you use the IP Helper API and the SetIpForwardEntry method to accomplish this.

Here is an article that walks you through how to implement it (with accompanying code):

http://www.developer.com/ws/pc/article.php/10947_3415521_2/IP-Helper-API-ARP-Routing-and-Network-Statistics.htm

Answer (score 0):

Though the question was answered about 7 years ago, I found a VERY easy way to do this in C# using netsh.exe.

This only works if you are running your program as administrator.

The command is:

netsh.exe interface ipv4 set interface "myNICsName" metric=20

To set the metric to 'Automatic' just set it to 0.
The high limit is 9999, but if you use something higher, it will just set it to 9999 for you.

To do this programatically, just use Process.Start in the following way:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = "netsh.exe",
                Arguments = $"interface ipv4 set interface \"{nicName}\" metric={metric}",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            }
        };

        bool started = p.Start();

        if (started)
        {
            if (SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => p.HasExited, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)))
            {
                Log.Write($"Successfully set {nicName}'s metric to {metric}");
                Log.Write($"Sleeping 2 seconds to allow metric change on {nicName} to take effect.");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                return true;
            }

            Log.Write($"Failed to set {nicName}'s metric to {metric}");
            return false;
        }
```

The above code also does some error checking to make sure the process indeed started and puts in a short delay so that the metric change can have a chance to take effect.  I found that I had some problems in my code when I didn't include the delay.